# Upload button is not responding to click event

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Hi I am new to node js and I want to upload a file to a server using jade, node js and express.

I recently created the following form using the jade template .

```
//HTML for creating the video uploader extends layout

 block content   h1= title
       form(name="uploadVideo",method="post",action="/uploadVideo")
       input(type="file", name="filePath")

 button#btnSubmit(type="submit") Upload
```

I added the following to the app.js

```
app.post('/uploadVideo',function(req,res) {
  console.log("Came here !!");   
});
```

However, clicking on the Upload button does nothing. What can I change to make it work ?

Comment: Did you try inserting a temporary middleware for debugging purposes higher up in your middleware/route chain to see if some other middleware/route is responding before your `/uploadVideo` POST route is reached?

Comment: I used node-inspector however, the app.post function does not get called when the Upload button is clicked. Do I have to add a listener to the button ? If yes where do I add that listener ?

Comment: On a related note, I should also mention that you'll probably want to set the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your form element so that the file gets submitted correctly.

Comment: Hi It still doesnt seem to respond to the uploadVideo Post req.

Comment: If your syntax indentation is correct in SO, that's pretty normal because your submit button is *not* inside your form.